# How to update a job in flink without loosing the state via UI and some backend state questions

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have the following code :

```
val stateUri = "file:///tmp/"

new RocksDBStateBackend(stateUri, true)
```

1. when I deploy new version of my job via ui what should I do in order to keep the state ?
2. Is it just enough to put the stateUri in the savepoint path ?
3. If I want to scale it out can I deploy the same jar again with the same path ?
4. what will happen if two different jars will have the same backend stateUri ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In order to upgrade your job, you first should take a savepoint via `bin/flink savepoint <JOB_ID> <TARGET_DIRECTORY>`. Alternatively, you can also cancel the job with a savepoint which creates a savepoint and stops the job `bin/flink cancel --withSavepoint <TARGET_DIRECTORY> <JOB_ID>`. Both CLI calls will return a path to the created savepoint which should be stored under your `TARGET_DIRECTORY`. In order to resume from this savepoint, you should enter this path into the *Savepoint Path* field in the UI or submit a job via `bin/flink run --fromSavepoint <SAVEPOINT_PATH> <JAR>`.
2. No, the `stateUri` is only the base path for the state backend where it stores the checkpoint. The state backend will create a sub directory with the id of the job under which it will store the checkpoints. Thus the path of a checkpoint usually looks like `stateUri/JOB_ID/chk-1` where `JOB_ID` is a UUID (e.g. `0ba86fd9d1b29d90796e4a7d27f9b2f9`) for the first checkpoint.
3. In order to scale out a job, you should take a savepoint, cancel the job and resubmit the job resuming from the savepoint and an increased parallelism (e.g. `bin/flink run --fromSavepoint <SAVEPOINT_PATH> --parallelism 10 <JAR>`).
4. Every job will have a unique job id. Therefore, you will find two sub directories under `stateUri` which are the different job ids. Checkpoints will be stored in each sub directory for each of the jobs separately.

Comment: Thank you very much Till for this informative, and detailed answer. according to your answer #3 I understand that in order to scale out, we must have a short downtime, correct ?

Comment: @igx Is there a downtime required?

Comment: At the moment the downtime is the time it takes to stop the job and to re-submit & restore from the taken savepoint. This time strongly depends on the size of your state.